# Creating 4 band image from RGB and grey scale image in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge, multi-band, band

I have an RGB image and a Gray scale image. I would like to merge them in a 4 bands image.

How can I do that?

Is there a simple way to do it from QGIS or I have to modify the image before to load them in QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the GDALTools plugin (Plugins->Manage Plugins... menu) and use the Merge tool (Raster->Miscellaneous menu) and tick the Layer stack option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have this message:Format driver JPEG does not support creation and piecewise writing.
Please select a format that does, such as GTiff (the default) or HFA (Erdas Imagine).

Comment: Ok,now it works, I've selected geotiff as output format. But now I have lost the exact georeferencing.